# How can I get the binding string in Angular

Tags: angular

Is there a way in Angular to get the binding expression (not the value) that is passed to an @Input property of a component?

Let's say I have the following model:

```
const model = { "user": { "name": "John" } }
```

I have a component with an input property called **name** that is bind to the **mode.user.name**.

```
<my-component [name]="model.user.name"></my-component>
```

Is there a way to access the exact binding expression inside the **my-component** code? In this case **"model.user.name"** string?

Please note that having a second attribute to pass the string expression separately is not an option. So something like this is not acceptable.

```
<my-component [name]="model.user.name" expression="mode.user.name"></my-component>
```

Comment: I think `my-component` does not have access to such information. It gets only the reference of the stuff that is being binded

Comment: Why do you need the model name in the component? I doubt there is a way to do what you are asking but you could do this on a second input: [bindingExpression]="'model.user.name'"

Comment: @DKidwell remove `[` and `]`, otherwise the value of the name will be passed once again

Comment: @Dorin Baba I have a second set of single quotes around the value so it should resolve to the string but you're right it may be clearer as bindingExpression="model.user.name"

Comment: @DKidwell sorry, I didn't noticed those `'`

Comment: I guess you could get to it if you go basic dom operation. Inside my-component, get the hosts native dom element and simply read the attribute? EDIT: hmm.. probably won’t just work now I think about it..

Comment: @MikeOne yea, something like that might be a solution. I guess one have to dive deep into the framework itself to get such information

Comment: @DorinBaba  I can imagine that this information is parsed by CLI at the compile time and may not be available at the runtime, unless there is such thing in Angular that describes the component and can specify what was originally bound to its properties.